# Can't access file selector inside iframe PhoneGap

Tags: php, android, html, image, cordova

So were working on a social networking website in phonegap, and basically the app just connects to a server that contains our website coded in php and HTML with some hooks for location and etc. But for some reason, when we click on "select file" it won't open up the image or file selector on Cyanogen Mod based roms. It works totally fine on Samsung's touchwiz but not on the CM 4.4 framework.

Would anyone be able to help in figuring out why it won't work in cm on phonegap?

Comment: that's how ends using non public API ... i mean PhoneGap's creators used it ... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220

Comment: Wow, I can't believe Google would just remove the functionality like that. Weve spent almost a year developing this app just to find out our main component won't work on 4.4... Not to mention everyone else out there with an app already in the app store using this. So absurd.